Archive of MLB stadium modifications
Is there an archive of modifications either to the dimensions or even just the wall heights for the various MLB stadiums? My interest is in park factors, but I wish to consider a modification such as Baltimore moving to a new stadium or Colorado raising the right field fences to be switching to a "new" stadium. Wikipedia pages and such are somewhat useful, but don't appear to be complete. Preferably, I would like to go back a few decades, and would be interested in changes to parks long since gone, such as Riverfront Stadium, Three Rivers Stadium, Tiger Stadium, etc.

Yes, there are several resources where you can find archives of modifications to MLB stadiums:
OOTP: This forum has a comprehensive collection of historical stadiums from 1901 to 2019, including models and park factors for each season. It’s a great resource if you’re interested in detailed historical data and visual models.
Of course, there's also the official MLB website: The official MLB website provides information on the history and evolution of ballparks, including modifications and renovations over the years.
Ballpark Digest: This site offers articles on the history and design of ballparks, including significant changes and trends in stadium architecture.
